# Line integral, parabola

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm brushing up on some multivariable-calc and I'm stuck on the following problem:

Calculate:

$$E = \int_\gamma \frac{-y \cdot dx+x \cdot dy}{x^2+y^2}$$
for $\gamma$ which is the parabola $y=2x^2-1$from $(1,1)$ to $(\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2})$.

I've done the following:

Let $$x(t)=t \implies x'(t)=1$$
$$y(t)=2t^2-1 \implies y'(t)=4t$$
for $\frac{1}{2} \le t \le 1$.
Thus $E$ becomes (unless I've done some error):
$$ E=-\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \frac{2t^2 + 1}{t^2+(2t^2-1)^2} dt$$
but I'm having trouble solving this. Would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea:

On the given domain the integrand function has a potential function (a primitive function):

$$F(x,y):=-\arctan\frac xy$$

So your integral's simply

$$F\left(\frac12\,,\,-\frac12\right)-F(1,1)\ldots\ldots $$

Answer (score 0):

Your function has antiderivative $$\tan^{-1}\frac{t}{1-2t^2}$$